# ADF Column Name Validation and Data Validation

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am trying to add some validation to my ADF pipeline. Is there a way to achieve the following validation in ADF?

1. Validate column header and return error message. There is a list of required column names that I need to check against the raw Excel file. For example, the raw file might have column A,B,C,D, but the required columns are A,B,E. So is there a way to validate and return an error message that the column E is missing in the raw file?
2. Validate the data type in data mapping flow, if column A should be a numeric field but some of the cells have text in it, or column B should be datetime type but has a number in it. Is there a way to check values in each row and return error message if the data validation fails on that row?

Comment: The above two requirements are depending on each other or different? it means one has to be done after other?

Comment: We need to validate if the required columns exist first then validate the data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to **@Nandan**, you can use Get Meta data activity structure like below.

This is my repro for your reference:

First, I have used 2 parameters for column names and Data types.

[image]

**Get Meta data activity:**

[image]

Get Meta activity output array:

[image]

Then I have created two arrays to get the above names and columns using forEach.

Then I have used two filter activities to filter the above parameter arrays.

The used if activity to check the parameter arrays length and filter activity output arrays lengths.

If its true, the inside True activities you can use your copy activity or Data flow as per your requirement. Inside False activities, use a fail activity.

**My pipeline JSON:**

```
{
"name": "pipeline1",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Get Metadata1",
            "type": "GetMetadata",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "Excel1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "fieldList": [
                    "structure"
                ],
                "storeSettings": {
                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Filtering names",
            "type": "Filter",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Getting names and columns as list",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.names",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "condition": {
                    "value": "@contains(variables('namesvararray'),item())",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Filtering types",
            "type": "Filter",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Filtering names",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@variables('typevararray')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "condition": {
                    "value": "@contains(variables('typevararray'), item())",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Getting names and columns as list",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.structure",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append names",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "namesvararray",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@item().name",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Append types",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            {
                                "activity": "Append names",
                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "typevararray",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@item().type",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "If Condition1",
            "type": "IfCondition",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Filtering types",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "expression": {
                    "value": "@and(equals(length(pipeline().parameters.names),activity('Filtering names').output.FilteredItemsCount),equals(length(pipeline().parameters.columns),activity('Filtering types').output.FilteredItemsCount))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "ifFalseActivities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Fail1",
                        "type": "Fail",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "message": "Some of the headers or types are not as required",
                            "errorCode": "240"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "ifTrueActivities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Set variable1",
                        "type": "SetVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "sample",
                            "value": "All good"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "names": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            ]
        },
        "columns": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": [
                "String",
                "String",
                "String"
            ]
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "namesvararray": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "typevararray": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "sample": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
}
```

**My pipeline failed and got error:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Rakesh! Just one question though what if I need to identify which required column name is missing from the Excel1, currently I can only tell if the required columns are existing or not.

Comment: you can use `@not(contains())` in filter condition and which gives the column names which are not in the excel files. But if you give like this, you have to change your if condtion also based on that. Give the if condition like if the length of filter output arrays is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a lookup activity on the dataset and return 1st row(with dataset header property disabled)this would give you the list of columns present in the excel file which you can then compare against the expected values, if the values/sequence match you can proceed further else you can thro error.
Note: you can also use Get meta data activity to get the column details

For data type, you can use column patterns in dataflows:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern

@rakeshGovindula: any more thoughts?

Comment: Hi Nandan, thanks for your reply, for the required column validation, when you say compare the 1st row with column name against the expected values, is this something can be done in the data mapping flow? Is there any example can be provided?